# Could not able to refer google-play-services.jar into my application

Tags: java, android, google-maps

hello friends need help...,

i am working with google map.. i followed all steps given in this link

https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw

the problem i am facing is google-play-services.jar is not referring to my application
but i am able to see google-play-services_lib.jar this jar file in buid path but not google-play-services.jar

any input is appreciable and thanks in advance..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved..
just said quick fix from class and then fix project
it asked me for add archeive file for google-play-services.jar